# rational map becomes a morphism after blow-ups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In dimension 2, a rational map becomes a morphism after a sequence of blow-ups. Does this still hold in higher dimensions?

Comment: In light of the comments under abx's answer, it might be a good idea to clarify the question a bit; in particular, do you require the blow-ups to be along smooth centers?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, but this is a very difficult result, due to Hironaka. To be precise : given a rational map $f:X --> Y$, there exists a birational morphism $b:\hat{X}\rightarrow X$, obtained as the composition of successive blown-up with smooth centers, such that $f\circ b$ is a morphism.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a reference? Or is this just in Hironaka's article on resolution of singularities?

Comment: Actually, you do not need Hironaka at all.  Let $X$ and $Y$ be projective schemes.  Let $f$ be a morphism from a dense open subset $U$ of $X$ to $Y$.  Let $\Gamma_f$ be the graph of $f$ inside $X\times Y$.  Let $\widehat{X}$ be the Zariski closure of $\Gamma_f$.  Then the projection, $b:\widehat{X}\to X$, is a projective, birational morphism.  Thus, by a theorem in Chapter II, Section 7 of Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry", the morphism $b$ is (isomorphic to) the blowing up of $X$ along a coherent sheaf of ideals.

Comment: @Jason: that's right, of course, but I believe the OP meant blow-ups with smooth centers (and rational map of smooth varieties).

Comment: @Timo Keller: Yes, this is in Hironaka's paper (Resolution of singularities of an algebraic variety over a field of characteristic zero", Ann. Of Math. (2) 79, 109–326. The statement is explained in CH. 0, §5.

Comment: @Serge and abx: Okay, that makes sense to me.

Comment: Sorry for the untimeliness. Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonsingular projective surfaces and let $f$ be dominant. Is Jason Starr's construction $\widehat{X}$ nonsingular in codimension 1 and $\mathrm{pr}_Y$ surjective?